Post-Job taking a long time in Azure DevOps Pipelines
I've had created 2 self hosted windows agents to run a set of specific pipelines.
Only problem is when at the end of every stage of every pipeline I run on these agents the Post-job step can take 10,15 sometimes even 20 minutes to complete. When it does it reports that it took less than 1 second.
Anybody got any ideas what the issue is, or even where to start looking for an answer.
I've tried various different pipelines, all hit the same issue when run on these agents


It's probably a UI problem - I've noticed that in some occasions I need to hit Ctrl-F5 to refresh the page.

It's not a UI problem, that was the first thing I thought of, refreshed the page multiple times, open new browser tab, tried a different browser. Wish it was that simple but it's not.

Does this happen at default agent or only happend at self hosted windows agents ? I think it related to your self hosted agent.

Is the post-job same or different between your pipelines? Is it repoduced on Microsoft-hosted agent? Please show some pipeline debug log. In addition, please check the two agent diagnostic logs(Worker diagnostic logs and Agent diagnostic logs) to confirm what it's doing in the post-job on self agent.

Thanks for the tip about the logs wade zhou. I will get hold of those and see what they say

You are welcome. On the two agent diagnostic logs, check if some operations are still running behind in the post-job task. You can post some log so we can check.

@wadezhou-MSFT - I have edited the original post to add an image of the logs that cover the time of the Post-Job step. Lots of retries and timeouts

Turned out the internal agents had been set up with the incorrect proxy settings for our corporate network. Got these reapplied and everything is now working as expected.
Thanks for all the suggestions - got me to the right answer in the end

As per the timeout and retries info on agent log, the agent has network connection issue to https://spsproduks1.vssps.visualstudio.com/....
It could be caused by the url is not added to firewall whitelist, or TLS 1.2 is not enabled on your agent.
You can try to ping spsproduks1.vssps.visualstudio.com on agent machine to check if it's reached.
To resolve the issue, please follow the doc Allowed Domain URLs, add the urls to the firewall whitelist.

If the issue persists, please also check for TLS 1.2, make sure it's enabled. Please find the detail steps from similar ticket.

Thanks for the info - I'll give this a try and then update here

You are welcome! The url needs to be accessible from your agent machine, so it can not happen the timeout from your log for post-job. Let me know if you have any queries.

Thanks for the pointers, get me to the answer

You are welcome! Glad to know it helps. Happy day!
